# Python - Outlook Personal Folder (.ost) integration - Save emails from folders to HDD

Tags: email, outlook, directory, backup

I use a personal folder (.ost) file that contains specific folders, and I save relevant emails into those folders. I want to save the content of each folder recursively to my hard drive, that contain the same folder structure.

If this could have a GUI that populates based on the folder names, and I could select the ones I want, from say a list box that would be awesome.

No idea what library to use that is easy and free...

Any help here would be appreciate, I am newish at Python, so keen to learn.

Thank you for your help!

I have searched the net and only found exchange type email integration, but that is not what I need. There does not seem to allot about this, else my search skills is, well, crap.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open standalone OST files - unlike PST files, they are tied to a particular mailbox and particular Outlook profile. If you mean using Outlook Object Model, there are numerous resources, including questions on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=outlook%20python). You can start at https://github.com/Hridai/Automating_Outlook

You'd need to create an instance of the `Outlook.Application` object, recursively loop through the folders starting at `Application.Session.Folders`, and process each folder to save messages ([MailItem.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.saveas)) and/or attachments ([Attachment.SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile)).